# Can I play all channels from multichannel audio with AUGraph

Tags: ios, core-audio

I'm using AUGraph to play music in my application. I have virtually same setup as in [Apple demo app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iPhoneMixerEQGraphTest/Introduction/Intro.html), only I operate on one bus. Now if I feed it multichannel audio (eg. [one of those](http://www.jensign.com/bdp95/7dot1voiced/)) I only hear first two channels. Same thing happens If I feed it to AVAudioPlayer so maybe that's how it should work on iOS but I don't like that.

Is there any way, using AUGraph, to somehow merge multiple channels so I can hear them all? Or maybe I can use more than one bus to play two channels on each? But then how would I go about getting other channels data?

Comment: The merging of the channels is the easy part. Using the sample code as an example, change `numbusses = 2` to however many channels - 6 or 8 - your source audio contains.  The trick is determining the correct ASBD parameters to use in place of `setCanonical`. Some searching should surface the answer pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to get all channels data. The important bit was setting interleaved flag on client file format (mClientFormat in Apple example) to false. This allows you to get number of channels you specify in AudioBufferList. Then you can just use one bus for one channels as Nick suggested.

Side effect is that quality of audio with 48kHz sample rate goes down a lot so there's still a bit of work ahead of me...